# Google Sheets Formula that finds employee with most hours worked for a specific location and shift (INDEX/MODE with multiple Criteria)

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas, google-query-language

In Google Sheets, I need to find out which employee works more than 50% of the hours for a given shift at a given location based on timecard data (Table in col G:J). In the attached google sheet I need a formula in Column C that returns the name of the matching employee useing Column A & B for criteria, then column D and E should auto calcuate.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HE90e1hVvsEIiFbNdb3sQ042LHMZhxyCno72eZMA79k/edit?usp=sharing

I was previously using an ArrayFormula with INDEX/IF/MODE/MATCH (example in cell C15) but that could only return the employee with the most shifts and was not able to differentiate by criteria.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in C2:D7 and use this in C2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A6&B2:B6, SORT(QUERY({H2:H&J2:J, G2:G, I2:I}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col1),sum(Col3) group by Col1,Col2"), 3, 0), {2, 4}, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much!